# How to transmit and receive data through serial UART port in DOSBox

Tags: x86, uart, dosbox, proteus

DOS provides a variety of [interrupts](http://www2.ift.ulaval.ca/%7Emarchand/ift17583/dosints.pdf) such as transmitting and receiving a word of data to/from a specific **COM** port. There are not enough guides on how to do that. After spending much time on it, I finally found the solution. This is a *self-answer* question and I introduce the solution in the answer section below.

I was simulating an STM32 project with Proteus, but before connecting the UART serial pins to a COMPIM, I tested whether the UART communication channel was working or not.

1. I connected a virtual terminal to a COMPIM, set the baud rate and other configs, and ran the simulation.[image]
2. Created a null-modem virtual COM port with *com0com* to connect the Proteus to DOSBox.
3. Changed DOSBox config files to set `serial1` to `COM1`:

   ```
   serial1=directserial realport:COM1
   ```
4. I expected to see printing a character after running this `x86` code in DOSBox (v0.74) but nothing happened.

```
; Initialize the UART configs
MOV AH,0
MOV AL,10100011B
MOV DX,0
INT 14H

; Send a character
MOV AH,01H
MOV AL,'C'
MOV DX,0
INT 14H
```

This code first sets the baud rate to 2400, with no parity, one stop bit, and 8-bit word. Then sends the `C` character to serial port.

Now this is my question, what is the right way to transmit a character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand why it was not possible to transmit or receive data with interrupts. Is it a DOSBox bug or my mistake? but found a way instead of using interrupts.

`COM1` has a `0x3F8` IO address in DOS. So if write 8-bit data in this address, it will be sent in this serial port! Like below:

```
MOV DX,03F8H
MOV AL,'C'
OUT DX,AL
```

Done :)

For receiving a character use `IN` instruction just like the `OUT` instruction.